# <mvc:resources> and PathVariable

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, spring-mvc, path-variables

Please help me to resolve the following issue! I have the config:

```
<mvc:resources location="/images/" mapping="/images/**"/>
<mvc:resources location="/css/" mapping="/css/**"/>
<mvc:resources location="/javascript/" mapping="/javascript/**"/>
```

and everything is working fine for my resources in requests like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/baraholka/viewAdverts.brh
```

but when I have request like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/baraholka/viewTagAdverts/tag/2/1
```

where:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/ajaxViewAdverts/tag/{id}/{currentPage}",      method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> viewTagAdverts(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, @PathVariable(value="currentPage") Integer currentPage, ModelMap map, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    byte view[] = {};
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
```

I get:

```
20:48:08.109  WARN [http-8080-4] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet:947  - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI     [/baraholka/viewTagAdverts/tag/2/javascript/jquery.cookies.2.2.0.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'baraholka'
20:48:08.109  WARN [http-8080-3] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet:947 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/baraholka/viewTagAdverts/tag/2/javascript/baraholka.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'baraholka'
20:48:08.140  WARN [http-8080-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet:947 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/baraholka/viewTagAdverts/tag/2/javascript/jquery.lightbox-0.5.min.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'baraholka'
20:48:08.156  WARN [http-8080-5] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet:947 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/baraholka/viewTagAdverts/tag/2/javascript/jquery.ui.stars.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'baraholka'
20:48:08.156  WARN [http-8080-2] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet:947 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/baraholka/viewTagAdverts/tag/2/css/jqcloud.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'baraholka'
20:48:08.171  WARN [http-8080-3] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet:947 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/baraholka/viewTagAdverts/tag/2/images/login.png] in DispatcherServlet with name 'baraholka'
20:48:08.171  WARN [http-8080-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet:947 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/baraholka/viewTagAdverts/tag/2/images/logo.png] in DispatcherServlet with name 'baraholka'
```

How to setup correct mapping? I also tried to do such mappings like **/images/** but it doesn't work.

Comment: The request mapping is for /ajaxViewAdverts/..., but the request is to /viewTagAdverts/...

Answer (score 1):

Also you could add your resources like this:

```
<base href="http://localhost:8080/" />
<link rel="icon" href="resources/images/favicon.ico" type="ico">
```

It's not so good solution, but i couldn't solved similar problem in my application with help another ways

Answer (score 0):

I looks like you use relative paths to refer to static resources in your templates, therefore browser treats them as relative to the current page, as you can see in the log.

You need to construct full paths with `<c:url>` instead, as follows:

```
<script src = "<c:url value = "/javascript/baraholka.js" />"></script>
```